# Capturing current state of a Gridview using dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

Hi and thanks in advance.

I wondering if someone can show me an example of getting the current state of a Gridview so that one may use it later to do something. I'm not sure if using the ViewState object is the correct approach to this or not and if so, I would need an example saving it to a ViewState and using it later for something.

I am using asp.net and c# with dynamic LINQ

Answer (score 0):

You can get the state from the row using `DataControlRowState`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate.aspx):

```
Member name Description
Alternate:  indicates that the data control row is an alternate row.
The Alternate state can be combined with other states, such as Normal, Edit, or Insert, at any time. These rows might be affected by the AlternateRowStyle property of the data control, if set.
Edit:   indicates that the row is in an edit state, often the result of clicking an edit button for the row. Typically, the Edit and Insert states are mutually exclusive.
Insert: indicates that the row is a new row, often the result of clicking an insert button to add a new row. Typically, the Insert and Edit states are mutually exclusive.
Normal: indicates that the data control row is in a normal state. The Normal state is mutually exclusive with other states except the Alternate state.
Selected:   indicates that the row has been selected by the user.
```

For exemple:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (rowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) != 0)
  {
     /*Do Stuff that you need here*/
  }
}
```